# cannot convert Task to TaskCollection

Tags: c#, collections

My testing code fragment:
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
     taskService = new ShimTaskService
            {
                TargetServerGet = () => "192.168.100.1", 
                UserNameGet = () => "user",
                UserAccountDomainGet = () => "TestDomain",
                UserPasswordGet = () => "p/w",
                RootFolderGet = () => new  ShimTaskFolder
                {
                   TasksGet = () =>  new List { new ShimTask {NameGet = () => taskName }};
                }
            }
            I have error:

```
        > Cannot convert lambda expression to type system.collections.generic.List< Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Task>
        > to return type system.collections.generic.List<
        > Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.TaskCollection>. How convert this
        > collection?    

                // TaskGet: 
                public FakesDelegates.Func<TaskCollection> TasksGet { set; }

                // TaskCollection:
                public sealed class TaskCollection : IEnumerable<Task>, IEnumerable, IDisposable
            {
                public int Count { get; }

                public Task this[int index] { get; }
                public Task this[string name] { get; }

                public void Dispose();
                public IEnumerator<Task> GetEnumerator();
            }
```

Comment: Why you have to create new collection `TaskCollection`?

Comment: Because TasksGet is func<TaskCollection> property

Comment: Since you don't show any constructors or operators on your custom `TaskCollection`, how can we possible answer this? How *do* you create a `TaskCollection` in your system?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the [TaskCollection from codeplex](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#19439), then you **cannot** create your own `TaskCollection` to wrap an arbitrary `Task`. That is not the intended usage. You will need to change your design, or change the source of the managed wrapper and rebuild the library.

Comment: I need testing some functionality with TaskScheduller. And I make Shim context.

Comment: @user2469940 you can't unit test something that isn't designed in a way that supports testability